# imported powershell module not visible when running via ssis package

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2012, interop, ssis-2012

I installed the `ImportExcel` module as described here:

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/5.0.1

Then I wrote a simple ps1 file that loops though certain folder and converts each xlsx file in that folder to csv format (using `ConvertFrom-ExcelSheet` method from the above module).

Finally, I wrapped that ps1 script into a .bat file.

That batch script works fine when executed manually via windows command line.

However, when the same batch file is executed from an SSIS package (on the same computer, under my credentials, using the standard Execute Process Task ), when the powershell script reaches the line calling ConvertFrom-ExcelSheet method, I am getting the following error:

```
The term 'ConvertFrom-ExcelSheet' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

- The PC was restarted after module installation.
- The module was installed with the AllUsers scope.
- Elevated shell during module installation.

Any hints what I can do to get this module working in SSIS? Or at least, where to start looking?

Environment:

- PowerShell 5.0.10586.117
- Windows 7 Enterprise x64
- Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by moving the installed module to user's module folder i.e. %USERPROFILE%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules

There is still no clear explanation why the module was not working from shared modules folder but at least the issue is now gone.